# Назначить одно событие другому

Tags: delphi

Есть два объекта с событиями одного типа:

```
TA = class
    e: TEvent;
end;

TB = class
    e: TEvent;
end;

...

a: TA;
b: TB;
```

И есть функция `event`, соответствующая типу `TEvent`. Далее выполняется такой код:

```
b.e := event;
a.e := b.e;
a.e();
```

В этом случае все работает, функция `event` вызывается из `a.e();`. Если строки поменять местами, то функция `event` уже вызываться не будет:

```
a.e := b.e;
b.e := event;
a.e();
```

Делаем вывод, что `a.e` хранит не указатель на `b.e`, но копию данных, поэтому присваивание `event` после `a.e := b.e` дает такой результат. Правильный вывод делаем? Есть ли пути обхода?

---

Кратко о ситуации. В реальности для обхода у объекта `a` приходится создавать метод, в котором единственной строкой идет вызов `b.e();`, и вот, чтобы избежать такого метода, захотел присвоить `a.e := b.e;`, чтобы он вызывался автоматически. Оказывается, что не всегда работает.

Comment: а с чего ему вдруг быть указателем на `b.e`? вы же там не берете никакой адрес и т.п. просто копируете текущее значение указателя `b.e`, которое `nil`.

Comment: @teran, может быть, не так выразился. Возможно, стоит в этом случае сказать "ссылка", как если бы мы делали присваивание `a := b` - объект `a` хранил бы в себе ссылку на `b`.

Comment: а собственно проверять `if assigned(b.e)` вы не собираетесь в коде своем?

Comment: @teran, это тестовый код, убрал все лишнее. В своем коде, конечно, проверяю.

Comment: дак значит вызов `b.e()` такие не единственная строка метода?

Comment: @teran, физически единственная, а логически - нет: `if (assigned(b.e) then b.e;`.

Comment: загвоздка то в чем? Очевидно используя эти же типы данных, решить проблему не получится. так что вам надо либо добавлять метод (или свойство) или менять тип `a.e` что бы он был ссылкой на `b`.

Answer (score 1):

> Делаем вывод, что a.e хранит не указатель на b.e, но копию данных

Естественно. a.e и b.e имеют одинаковый тип. Как одно может хранить указатель на другое?

Они оба хранят указатели на функцию. И при присваивании `a.e := b.e;` создается еще одна копия указателя на функцию, а не на поле объекта b

Comment: Для обьединения событий в группы в delphi существует ActionList

Answer (score 1):

```
b.e := event;
//b записывает в книжку на странице "если прорвало трубу:" - телефон сантехника 222333  
a.e := b.e;
//а переписывает в свою книжку на такую же страницу: телефон сантехника 222333 
a.e();
//трубу прорвало, a звонит по телефону 222333

a.e := b.e;
//а переписывает в свою книжку на странице "если прорвало трубу:"   а нечего писать
b.e := event;
//b записывает в книжку на странице "если прорвало трубу:" - телефон сантехника 222333  
a.e();
//трубу прорвало, в книжке пусто, a топится
```